# Javascript, ação sobre um texto selecionado

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

Galera gostaria de saber como fazer uma ação sobre um texto selecionado no textarea, por exemplo selecionei a palavra 'oi' e quando eu clicar em um botão com o Onlick, mudasse o texto para 'tchau'.

Aguardo a resposta, pois estou o dia todo procurando e não acho. Agradeço a sua atenção.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você pode utilizar os atributos `selectionStart` e `selectionEnd` do `textarea` para determinar que trecho do mesmo está selecionado. Então é só substituir esse trecho em seu valor (`value`).

Exemplo (pega o valor até o início da seleção, junta com a string a inserir, e fecha com o valor após o final da seleção):

```js
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
  var ta = document.querySelector("textarea");
  ta.value = ta.value.substring(0, ta.selectionStart) +
             "tchau" +
             ta.value.substring(ta.selectionEnd);
}
```

```html
<textarea>oi, tudo bem?</textarea>
<button>Trocar</button>
```

Comment: Po cara me salvou, você não tem noção do quando eu estava procurando isso, estava fazendo teste com o .select(), mas nada. Obrigado mesmo.

Answer (score 3):

Aí está um exemplo usando puro javascript:

```js
function selecionaTexto() {
  var textArea = document.getElementById('texto');
  var selectedText;

  if (textArea.selectionStart != undefined) { //Se tiver algo selecionado
    var startPos = textArea.selectionStart; //Inicio da selecao
    var endPos   = textArea.selectionEnd;     //Fim da selecao
    selectedText = textArea.value.substring(startPos, endPos);
    if (selectedText == "Oi") { //Se selecao foir "Oi"
      var novoTexto = textArea.value.substring(0, startPos) +
                      "Tchau" + textArea.value.substring(endPos);
      textArea.value = novoTexto;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="texto">Oi senhor usuário</textarea>
</br>
<button id="botao" onclick="selecionaTexto();">Trocar</button>
```

Comment: Po cara muito Show agradeço a sua atenção. Muito obrigado mesmo.